# How to use cv::findcontours and DFT? It causes debug error

Tags: c++, opencv, contour, dft

What I am doing is after pre-processing the image (by thresholding) find contours of the Image.
And I want to get the Discrete Fourier Descriptor of each contours (using dft() function)
My code follows,

```
vector<Mat> contourLines1;
vector<Mat> contourLines2;

getContourLine(exC1, contourLines1, binThreshold, numOfErosions);
getContourLine(exC2, contourLines2, binThreshold, numOfErosions);

// calculate fourier descriptor
Mat fd1 = makeFD(contourLines1.front());
Mat fd2 = makeFD(contourLines2.front());

/////////////////////////

void getContourLine(Mat& img, vector<Mat>& objList, int thresh, int k){
  threshold(img,img,thresh,255,THRESH_BINARY);
  erode(img,img,0,cv::Point(-1,-1),k);
  cv::findContours(img,objList,CV_RETR_LIST,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
}

/////////////////////////

Mat makeFD(Mat& contour){
  Mat result;
  dft(contour,result,DFT_ROWS); 
  return result;
}
```

What is the problem??? I can't find it.. I think the type of parameters of functions (such as cv::finContours or dft ) is wrong....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output of findContours is vector< vector< Point > >. You are providing vector< Mat>. This is a legitimate use (although a bit obscure), but you have to remember that the type elements in matrix is 'int'. DFT on the other hand works only with matrices of floats. This is what causes the crash. You can use [convertTo](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-convertto) function to create matrices of proper type.

Also I am not sure that the output will have any meaning to whatever computation you are doing. As far as I know Fourier transform supposed to work with signal, not with coordinates that are extracted from it.

Just a stylistic remark: cleaner way to perform same threshold is

```
img = (img > thresh);
```